# Wireless interference on both 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz every 10 seconds

Tags: wireless-networking, interference

One wireless router and two wireless access points. Have tried both 2.4Ghz (different channels) and 5Ghz. Even at a distance of only 1 meter from the router, there is significant interference every 10 seconds causing 1000-2000 ms roundtrips when pinging or packet loss. Otherwise the roundtrip times are 2-3 ms.

The interference appears across the entire house. Have tried shutting down electrical equipment but to no avail. Have tried all ethernet cabling in the house and there is no problem with interference over the wired connections.

I have updated router firmwares, increased and decreased transmission signal strengths, tried to run only one router at a time etc. Network is limited to only 802.11n/ac to prevent issues with older devices, and firewall is disabled.

What could the cause be, since it hits both frequency bands at the same time hard? A radio transmitter in the area? Interference caused by high currents?

Comment: It could be anything that use wifi, like remote cam. I had baby cam that use to scramble my wifi, my iphone near and the wifi drop.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the issue is impacting both frequencies, I doubt it is being caused by Wireless interference.  Instead, I suspect the problem may be the router itself.  Have you tried swapping it out for another device?

Comment: The wired part works just fine, I have also tried disabling the radio on the router and all AP:s and enabling the radio on an AP I know worked at another location just last week... but still the interference, no matter where I am in the house.